# Testing only individual functions in a R script

Tags: r, unit-testing

I am trying to test a individual functions in a R script which contains a function call as the last statement of the script i.e. Here is the R code:

```
mul.R
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

mul <- function(n, m) {
        prod <- n * m
        return (prod)
}


mul(4,5)
```

Here is the test script:

```
test_simpleProgram.R
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library('RUnit')
source("./../simpleProgram.R")

test.mul <- function() {
        checkEqualsNumeric(mul(n= 2,m= 3), 4)
}
```

I execute the test script using the following command:

```
runTestFile(absFileName= file.path("test_simpleProgram.R"))
```

Now, when I source the R script I want to test i.e. `mul.R`, since the last statement already makes a call to the `mul` function, the entire script is executed and then the test script runs the function again. This makes the 1st execution(due to `source(..)`) not needed for testing purpose.

Is there a way to test such scripts, without running the script when sourcing it in the test script?

Comment: Develop a package with tests?

Comment: you can create a library file that only contains your `mul` function and maybe even `test.mul`. Then both your script and test script will source that file.

Comment: @mnel: Having worked on few programming languages, I am accustomed to not creating a package just to test a particular piece of code. And I would prefer not creating a package every time I have to test it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `parse` instead of `source`:

```
code <- parse("c:/R/mul.R") # actual file path may vary
```

This load the file as unevaluated expression. It can be seen as:

```
# > as.list(code)
# [[1]]
# mul <- function(n, m) {
#     prod <- n * m
#     return(prod)
# }
# 
# [[2]]
# mul(4, 5)
```

The first element of the list above is actually a call to the `'<-'` function:

```
# > as.list(code[[1]])
# [[1]]
# `<-`
# 
# [[2]]
# mul
# 
# [[3]]
# function(n, m) {
#     prod <- n * m
#     return(prod)
# }
```

The second element, OTOH, is a call to the `mul` function:

```
# > as.list(code[[2]])
# [[1]]
# mul
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 5
```

So, if your files are made of assignments and undesired function calls, we can identify that by inspecting the first element of each entry in the list above:

```
filter <- sapply(code, function(x)as.character(x[[1]])=="<-")

# >filter
# [1] TRUE FALSE
```

Now we can evaluate only the assignments:

```
eval(code[filter], envir=globalenv())
```

Then you can call your `test.mul` function. You can use these statements to replace you `source` call.

This can generalized to other filters. For instance, if you want to evaluate all statements except the last one, you can just use this:

```
eval(code[-length(code)], envir=globalenv())
```